# How do I force a reference of a table that does not exist

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to force reference a table that does not exist.

Is this possible?

To replicate what I am trying to do, open Excel, create a new worksheet and in A1 enter

```
=MyMadeUpTable[[#Headers],[Some Header]]
```

Excel will tell you off because there is no such table called `MyMadeUpTable1`

I need to force this change, and accept that Excel will be unhappy and not reference correctly.

This is because this will be a template. My VBa macro will be generating  table with the valid table name at a later stage

Comment: Why don't you have the same macro generate the reference after it's created the table?

Comment: Because I can not work out how to detect a table in a Worksheet. I did try that first, failed, so am trying an alternative. You are right, it is the better approach

Answer (score 0):

You can create the formula using `INDIRECT()` to generate the table name from a value in a cell or Named Range. There's some... "et cetera"... to this approach though.

Another way would be to create the file with Table or Tables present, just named "Table1" and so on. Your VBA can then just rename them when it needs them and work from that point. Given you seem to know the names, you could name them as you create their empty placeholder Tables in the template, and simply let your VBA fill them. This way, all references to them are valid even before use.

Selecting them in VBA is the same as selecting anything else. And since they already exist, there's no need to test for their existence — "detecting them" — (well, except for "good practice"...).